# How can I change one of my three buttons colors on click to blue but make it so that only one can be blue at a time?

Tags: java, xml

I want to make it so that when I switch between buttons one button will be blue while the other two will remain gray. This means that if I click a new button that button should then become blue and the previously clicked buttons should go back to their original color.

#### Xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
      android:text="Button"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="136dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="136dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
      android:text="Button"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="236dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="236dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
      android:text="Button"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Java

I can change all of the buttons colors to blue but I'm struggling to make it so that only one at a time is blue while the other two are their original rgb color.

```
package com.example.scrolltes1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button1:
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    button1.setBackgroundColor(v.getId() == R.id.button1 ? Color.BLUE : Color.GREY);
    button2.setBackgroundColor(v.getId() == R.id.button2 ? Color.BLUE : Color.GREY);
    button3.setBackgroundColor(v.getId() == R.id.button3 ? Color.BLUE : Color.GREY);
}
```